# how to add attributes / objects to root window DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to add new attributes to DOM Window tree.
1. An String.
2. Object like :

```
Object { xxx=function(),  yyy=function(),  zzz=function(),  more...}
```

Comment: You want to add attributes to the `window` object? Just don't use `var` and you are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create attributes in root DOM, you can just add Global Variables:

```
<script>
//for function
function newFunc() {}
//for String
globalAttribute = "thevalue";
//for Object
     function classname() {
     }
     classname.prototype = {
        func1: function() {
            return "login";
        },
        func2: function () {
            return null;
        }
     };
     theGlobalName =  Object.create(classname.prototype);
</script>
```

This script tag can be either placed in html / js / jsp files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add an object to dom tree , just by assigning function or variable or object to the window object

( even declaring without var Or using window.yourObject = ...; )

here is a n exemple

```js
object = { foo:function(){alert("hello")}, bar : function(){alert("Man");}}
window.addedToDom = object;

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
  addedToDom.foo();
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">click Here</button>
```